# How to convert a view to pdf and save it into a folder on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext, rotativa

I am new in this field.
I am trying to convert my view into pdf and save it to a folder on my website server by clicking on button. I am using .net mvc with razor view. My view contain payment details of products and customer details.
I am trying to finding it on Google but I am getting failed. Please help.

Comment: I think its best to start with the first problem: convert a view to pdf. Can be tricky I guess. Have you gound a library that can do that?

Comment: Hi! Could you please add a little bit more context to your question. What does your view look like, what have you tried so far, etc.

Comment: there is a working sample for itext here https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/MVC-iTextSharp-Example-Convert-HTML-to-PDF-using-iTextSharp-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx